# How to reference MigraDoc in a C# project?

Tags: c#, .net, pdfsharp, migradoc

Sorry for the stupid question, but how do I reference MigraDoc? I'm trying like this but no luck so far:

`using PDFsharp.MigraDoc;`

I'm in a .NET project, this is the reference line in the *.sln

`<PackageReference Include="PdfSharp.MigraDoc" Version="2.0.1" />`

Comment: Did you check the product's samples, documentation? Looks like [the namespace](http://www.nudoq.org/#!/Packages/PDFsharp-MigraDoc-GDI/MigraDoc.DocumentObjectModel/MigraDoc) is `MigraDoc`, not `PdfSharp.MigraDoc`

Comment: I also tried MigraDoc with no luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, get an official version like this one:
https://www.nuget.org/packages/PDFsharp-MigraDoc-WPF/1.50.4845-RC2a

Version 2.0.1 is not the official MigraDoc version.

The start with `using` statements as shown here:

```
using MigraDoc.DocumentObjectModel;
using MigraDoc.DocumentObjectModel.Tables;
```

Sample source code can be found here:
https://github.com/empira/MigraDoc-samples
https://sourceforge.net/projects/pdfsharp/files/pdfsharp/PDFsharp%201.50%20%28beta%203%29/

Comment: Thank you. This works. Do you know how to differenciate an 'official' version in nuget?

Comment: Official PDFsharp/MigraDoc NuGet packages are published by user PDFsharp-Team. https://www.nuget.org/profiles/PDFsharp-Team

Comment: @R01010010 official versions are published by the *creator/owner* of a library. `PdfSharp.MigraDoc` was created by some other guy and was last updated 3 years ago.

Comment: is there any way to get rid of WPF reference when dealing with migradoc?

Comment: @vmachacek The GDI build of PDFsharp does not use WPF. The Core build for .NET 6 (coming soon, but no ETA yet) uses neither GDI+ nor WPF.